# Proper REST architecture for system that has multiple request types

Tags: rest, architecture

I am designing a system that has multiple request types. For example, a user can "join" an organization or "register" for an event (and many other types).

So I have

```
GET /memberships?organization=125
GET /registrations?event=2556
```

etc.

Over time the system has evolved to allow a request system, so users first **request** to join an org, which is then approved by the admin, which then turns into an an actual membership. Similarly, a user **requests** to register for an event, which an admin approves or rejects, etc.

This leads to a lot of redundant business objects and design:

```
POST /membership_requests {organization:"125",user:"200"}
GET /registration_requests {event:"2556",user:"200"}
```

Begs the question, should I have a single request system which can support multiple types?

```
POST /requests {user:"200",type:"event",item:"2556"}
```

- Upside: single place for requests, easier queries, single code base for all requests
- Downside: I no longer can query `GET /membership_requests?organization=125` but instead need to do `GET /requests?type=organization&item=125`

It is a more generic system, but the queries seem strange.

I know, this is somewhat opinion-based, but looking for the experience of people here as to the impact of going down one path vs the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like either way would be okay, so the way to decide is, which would make the system simpler? 
My experience has been that choosing for the one request system becomes LESS simple IF you have to handle different kinds of requests differently.

In other words, if your request system is likely to end up with code like

```
if(type=organisation){ 
    do this
}else if(type=othertype){
    do that
}else if (type=...){
}
```

then that would be a bad sign. But if you expect to handle all different request types with the same code with no such if statements, then your single system probably is simpler.

The queries aren't really that strange. If you have a request system though, would you not end up with a requestId, so that `type=organization&item=125` turns into `request=123456` ?

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about that as well. It sounds like you are saying, there is no simple solution, there will be trade-offs either way.

Comment: And. yes, `type=organization&item=125` (requests to join organization 125) are the equivalent of `request=123456`, but the latter is a GET single item by ID and the former is a search.

Comment: Just a follow-up: This week I implemented a notification system. Each time a user opens a request, s/he gets a notification that there is a pending request, as do admins to approve it. Each time an admin approves or rejects, the user gets a notification. This led to a lot of duplicate code for each request type. I should have gone down the unified path... and may yet.